# Finding value in a table and getting the index

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a value on a table, and getting an index on the same row. Something like this:
I have a table like this:

```
name id1    id2     id3

Jorg pear   --     apple

Anna lemon banana   --
```

and on another page I have this:

```
pear

apple

lemon 

banana
```

And I want the match like this

```
pear jorg

apple jorg

lemon anna

banana anna
```

Does anyone know a quick way to do it? I tried with match to find the row and then triying to find the cell but I wasn't able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE not MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$D$3)/($B$2:$D$3=F2),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this it works, I don't understand the aggregate part, do you main explain how it works? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1502668 it returns the minimum row number  where `$B$2:$D$3=F2` returns true